Detect character encoding of file in SQL Server
I'm writing a program to read the contents of text files on my SQL Server instance. Usually, for a .log file or .txt file, it is non-Unicode, so SINGLE_CLOB would be used in the query:
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Temp\sample_log_file.log', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents;

However, every once in a while I'll stumble across a file that has some Unicode characters in it. Hence, I would have to write the query with SINGLE_NCLOB:
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Temp\sample_text_file.txt', SINGLE_NCLOB) AS Contents;

If not, I'll get the error:

SINGLE_NCLOB requires a UNICODE (widechar) input file. The file specified is not Unicode.

These are not ad hoc queries or T-SQL; I'm running a program. So my question is, how I can detect the character encoding of a file before trying to parse it in a query? Or really, how do I check if a file is Unicode or non-Unicode (ASCII)? Seems simple, but I can't find anything.

Additional *.csv/txt flat files problems: column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data. Or data elements are missing completely, i.e. column positions will vary.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, encoding, and enforce data quality.

@YitzhakKhabinsky Thank you for your response. I don't plan on changing these CSV and text files to XML. The program I'm running browses all files on the drives of the database server, then shows contents of the file on click. So, existing system files written as .csv or .txt would have to be bulk updated by me to XML format.

@TN Thank you for your response. As far as I'm concerned, using OPENROWSET() is about the only way to read the contents of a file in SQL Server. Is there an alternative way I could open a file and check for BOMs, UTF-16LE characters, etc. before I decided whether or not to use SINGLE_CLOB or SINGLE_NCLOB? The real only feasible way I could is in the form of a query.

@MaxVoisard - I believe you can use SINGLE_BLOB to get the raw data as VARBINARY(MAX) and then extract individual bytes using SUBSTRING() like SUBSTRING(@blob, 1, 2) = 0xFFFE or SUBSTRING(@blob, 1, 3) = 0xEFBBBF.

@TN Thank you, that seemed to work! You can post an answer and I will mark as correct.

There is no foolproof way, but with some logic you can make an educated guess.
By examining the first few bytes of the file in binary mode, the presence of Byte Order Marks (BOMs) can identify some encodings with high confidence: FF FE for UTF-16LE (little-endian), FE FF for UTF-16BE (big-endian), and (unofficially) EF BB BF for UTF-8 are the most common. However, BOMs are optional, so this technique is only a partial solution.
Beyond that, you can use pattern matching to make educated guesses: Alternating (mostly) zero and non-zero bytes likely indicates UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE. All bytes <= 7E usually means ASCII or some national variant. If bytes in the range 80-BF are present and always preceded either by a another byte 80-BF or a byte C0-FF, that probably means UTF-8 (additional checks may be needed). Otherwise, you may have some single-byte extended ASCII encoding, such as Windows-1252 or Codepage 850, among many other possibilities.
Such tests are not guaranteed. In particular languages using non-Latin alphabets will make encoding detection more difficult.
As for the implementation details, I believe you can use SINGLE_BLOB option to get the raw data as VARBINARY(MAX). After that, you can extract individual bytes or byte sequences using SUBSTRING() for analysis. For example:
SUBSTRING(@blob, 1, 2) = 0xFFFE    -- UTF-16LE BOM
SUBSTRING(@blob, 1, 3) = 0xEFBBBF  -- UTF-8 BOM

The additional pattern matching logic would be much more involved, requiring scanning the entire blob to gather statistics and (for UTF-8) to check for valid multi-byte sequences.
